# Converting arrays of datetimes to pandas datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of datetime's in python:

```
array([datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 15, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 18, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 21, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 15, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 18, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 21, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 15, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 18, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 21, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

How do I convert this into dattetimeindex:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-25 06:47:11.454232', '2017-03-26 06:47:11.454232',
               '2017-03-27 06:47:11.454232', '2017-03-28 06:47:11.454232',
               '2017-03-29 06:47:11.454232', '2017-03-30 06:47:11.454232',
               '2017-03-31 06:47:11.454232'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(1-d array)`

Comment: @NickilMaveli couldn't be bothered to put that in an answer box?  

Comment: @piRSquared: More so because `pd.to_datetime` has become sort of a cliche. I don't know, maybe it's better to close such questions while commenting itself and also the OP didn't put forth their tried attempts too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
array_date_time_index = pd.to_datetime(array)
```

Well, someone solicitated that explain why this works, but I don't have a deep knowledge for this...Well, it's a short history, I needed it for my job and found that it works pretty well, and was enough for me... but if someone needs a deeper knowlegdge, he/she can see the pandas documentation web site, where is well explained:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65429075/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.